# Model does not get passed from controller to factory and webAPI

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

**My problem**

I have created a factory based on the same model as controller for my page.
The problem I have, is that the $scope.model doesn't get to the factory and thus to the webAPI service which in turn of course returns an error because the object of the webAPI method is empty.

FYI: in the code below `app` is correctly defined with angular.

```
app.controller('SFOptionsPageController', function ($scope, $http, $location, sfNgLabelsService, saveOptionsDataService) {

$scope.model = { name: 'Me', lastName: 'Last', address: { street: 'streetName', number: 458 }}

[A bit further in my code...]

// Form submit handler that sents my model to the factory, or at least it should.
$scope.submit = function(form) {
    if ($scope.form.$valid) {
        saveOptionsDataService.post(
            $scope.model,            
            function (result, getResponseHeaders) { },
            function (response) { }
        );      
        window.location = $scope.nextPage;
    }
    else {
        $scope.submitted = true;
    }
}
```

The above code calls my factory below correctly, which is not my only factory, so I presume that therein lies the problem?:

```
'use strict';
app.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json;charset=utf-8,*/*;q=0.9';
});

app.factory('savePersonalDetailsDataService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/bll/api/ControllerName/savepersonaldetails', {}, {
        post: {
           method: 'POST'
        }
   });
});

app.factory('saveOptionsDataService', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/bll/api/ControllerName/saveoptionsdata', { }, {
        post: {
            method: 'POST'
        }
    });
});
```

The factory above calls my .NET webAPI method but that one returns an error stating my object is empty which isn't allowed of course.

**My question**

Why doesn't my model get passed through even though I see it in the request payload when I check the debugger of Chrome? 
How can I resolve this?